# Script blazor.web.js interferes with client-side JS logic in Blazor Web App Net8

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

I am starting with Blazor Web App with Net8, and I am having issues making the interaction of my DOM elements work. Basically, I have a menu with dropdown elements. I have constructed the HTML in my layout, and through a call in a  tag, I assign events to the elements of my DOM. All done through JavaScript

> At the time of creating the Blazor Web App project, I selected:
>
> Interactive Render Mode: Server

**MainLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        window.myCompany.mainLayout.addLayoutEvents();
    });
</script>

// HTML Code
```

Basically, when the addLayoutEvents method is executed, events start to be assigned to the elements in the DOM, among which there are elements of type "".

**App.razor**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/core.bundle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyWeb.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/core.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here, what needs to be noted is that I am attaching a JS file (core.bundle/js) in which the method "**addEventLayout**" has been defined and consumed in "**MainLayout.razor**."

When proceeding to execute my page, I see that it doesn't behave as it should. The menus do not expand. Upon reviewing and tracking it with the browser debugger, I have noticed that the execution reaches certain lines within the "**blazor.web.js**" script, which disrupts the behavior that had already been executed. In other words, my JS method "**addEventLayout**" does what it should by expanding the menus, but the execution of the lines within "**blazor.web.js**" undoes this quickly. I have tried removing the reference to the "**blazor.web.js**" script in the ***App.razor*** file, and everything works wonderfully. However, I believe that removing the reference is not the most appropriate solution and that this file likely serves functions that I am still discovering.

In this regard, will this "**blazor.web.js**" file definitely interfere with the UI logic that I am developing purely on the client side (JS)?

Is there a way to prevent its execution without adversely affecting any other client-side execution?

Thanks in advance.